# PHP Get $_POST result from form

Tags: php, post, model-view-controller

I am creating multiple forms using a foreach statement. 
I want to retrieve the $_POST value that my paragraph id is set to when the user click the button. 
I don't know how to use $_POST in my displayTeacherProfile function in this case since I don't know what the exact value of my paragraph id is set to.

```
<?php foreach ($data['teachers'] as $teachData): ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="/MVC/teacher/displayTeacherProfile" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $teachData['username_email'] ?></td>
        <td><p class="form-control-static" name="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"
               id="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"><?php echo $teachData['language_name'] ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="continueButton" name="action" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                    value="Search">Visit Profile
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in a very wrong direction my friend.

First of all You can't put a form in between table and tr

the structure of table is

**table < tr < td** You cant put it like **<strike>table < form < tr < td</strike>**

If you inspect your code then you can see what i was saying.

To maket it happen put the form in **td** or outside **table** as per requirement

In your case use it inside **td**.

after that you can't get the value of paragraph id in post data. You have to create a form field to get that data.

In your case that would be a hidden field.

So the code will be somthing like this

```
<?php foreach ($data['teachers'] as $teachData): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $teachData['username_email'] ?></td>
        <td><p class="form-control-static" name="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"
               id="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"><?php echo $teachData['language_name'] ?></p>
        </td>
    <td>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/MVC/teacher/displayTeacherProfile" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="teacher_id" value="<?php echo $teachData['person_id'] ?>">
             <button name="action" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                    value="Search">Visit Profile
            </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It will give you data in `$_POST['teacher_id']`

This will work.

I will suggest you to use GET instead of POST. Check this link

[When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get#answer-46614)

Check this code for **$_GET**

```
<?php foreach ($data['teachers'] as $teachData): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $teachData['username_email'] ?></td>
        <td><p class="form-control-static" name="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"
               id="<?php $teachData['person_id'] ?>"><?php echo $teachData['language_name'] ?></p>
        </td>
    <td>
         <a href="/MVC/teacher/displayTeacherProfile?person_id=<?php echo $teachData['person_id'] ?>" class="btn btn-default" 
                >Visit Profile
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```